# Multi-writer FME

Tags: fme-form

I have heaps of tables to update as part of data management and transition process. All feature classes are identically kept under separate environments (e.g., SDE, gdb and MapInfo)

[image]

I am using FME to convert and update the datasets first from shapefile to SDE (using GEODATABASE_SDE writer), then data transition to FILEGDB and MITAB etc. To automate and reduce the time I am creating multi-writer script to update the datasets identically as follows:

[image]

Multi-writer (FME) script runs well. It is writing the data in specified feature datasets (in SDE) but is not writing identically in FILEGDB (creating feature classes openly at the end in GDB).

*I searched through docs.safe.com and found that “The writer exports data to a new or existing File Geodatabase using the File Geodatabase API. Note that, because they are considered to have complex behavior, the Geodatabase API writer does not support writing to tables that participate in a relationship.*)

GEODATABASE_SDE appears with the ‘format parameters’ to specify the featuredataset. However, it is not available in FILEGDB.

[image]

[image]

I guess, I am not giving the correct parameters.

Anyone using multi-writers through FME got an idea to deal with, please share knowledge and help.

My results are
GEODATABASE_SDE writer

[image]

and FILEGDB

[image]

Whereas, feature classes should sit in feature dataset 'Administrative'.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you have ArcGIS Desktop installed on the same machine as FME.  If you do, you will gain access to another File GeoDatabase writer.  The ArcObjects one.

If you use that one, you will get several additional options that you don't get in the API writer.  The one you need is the ability to specify a Feature Dataset.

See below image:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: ESRI Geodatabase (File Geodb ArcObjects) is a good choice, but it is not carrying forward all the attributes.Rather it carries only ObjectID, Shape, Shape.Area and Shape.len. Selecting Dynamic properties (giving schema source as reader), it writes all attributes as source, but ignores all other transformer settings (e.g., AttributeRenamer settings).

Individually using FileGeodb ArcObject writer, works perfectly taking care of all filters and transformers. Using it as multi-writer, it loose a lot.

I tried all settings, no success yet.

Really there is something hidden.

Comment: Also, I found that using File Geodb Arcobjects as 1st writer and Geodatabase SDE writer at second place, put inverse effect on writers. It writes the features as required (using filters and AttributeRenaming in FILEGDB but ignores for GEODATABASE_SDE.